# Can you make latte-art with a panarello wand?

Tags: equipment, coffee, milk, steaming

I have a deLonghi Icona coffe machine. It contains a steaming wand of the panarello kind (with a hole in the top that automatically injects air). I tried to steam the milk to create a microfoam that would behave correctly when pouring into coffee. No success though.

My question is - is it possible to make a correct foam that would create latte-art on pouring with this kind of wand? Or do I need a machine with other wand type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.  And it is not too easy.

Microfoam has small bubbles by definition and the panarello wand will draw a 'certain' amount of air and you can't really control that part.  The notes below might help you get there.  I have successfully done this with the panarello wands of automatic Saeco machines which aren't too different from deLonghi.

- Run your steam wand in a cup water first until it's fully producing steam and not spuddering hot water mixed with steam.
- Use a small Stainless Steel Milk Frothing Pitcher.  If the wand is trying to blow steam and air in for a long time, you'll end up with big bubbles.  That wand is not as powerful as a commercial espresso machine with a proper boiler.
- 'Stretch' the froth only for a few seconds in the beginning.
- Keep the wand off-center in the pitcher to encourage circulation (see next point).
- Most important: make sure you create a whirlpool to circulate the milk (helps to gently move the pitcher in a circular motion to encourage the start of the whirlpool).
- I use the fattiest milk I can find.

> The trick is to move the milk in a circulation such that big bubbles
>   break and only microbubbles survive.  Some microfoam creation also
>   happens at the vortex of the whirlpool.

Comment: Finally, before pouring the foamed milk, knock the pitcher on the counter a couple of times (presumably to remove the large bubbles) and swirl it around a bit (while the bottom remains firm on the counter).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by removing the outer "Panarello" wand and using the inner steam wand to stretch my milk, it gives you much more control and with a little practice it works a treat and produces nice glossy stretched milk perfect for latte art.